# Asterisk / FreePBX - Perform action when receiving a call

Tags: asterisk, voip, phone-call, pbx

I'm using FreePBX and have this configuration in ***extensions_custom.conf*** so that I can receive a notification via *Pushover*.

```
[macro-dialout-trunk-predial-hook]
exten => s,1,System(/usr/bin/sendpush.php "Call from ${CALLERID(num)} to ${OUTNUM}")
```

I also need to receive notifications on incoming calls, but can't figure it out on what context should I apply it.
(If it makes any difference, I'm using 4 trunks and want notifications from all of them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by just adding:

```
[ext-did-custom]
exten => s,1,System(/usr/bin/sendpush.php "External call from ${CALLERID(num)}")
```

Comment: Please consider implication of malicious external data--something like `133"; rm /etc/asterisk/extensions.conf; printf "pwned?`--if a caller manages to pass this in as caller-id via some method it would spell trouble--no?

Answer (score 0):

Use ami events interface or hire expert

Predial hook seams not work in current freepbx.

Currently it like this

```
exten => s,n(gocall),Macro(dialout-trunk-predial-hook,)
```

That mean you have re-define in extensions.conf this part:

```
[macro-dialout-trunk-predial-hook]
exten => s,1,MacroExit()
```

But that work on OUTBOUND calls.